# Prevent splitting Window when using pythoncomplete in Vim

Tags: python, autocomplete, vim

I'm using VIM with pythoncomplete. When I'm making a completion, the current window is splitted and calltips are shown in the upper pane. I hate that! Is there a way to prevent that behavior or at least limit the size of the upper pane automaticly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```

This will prevent the opening of the preview window.